# Why my controller does not show all belongs_to objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: tournament and round.

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rounds

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 3..64 }
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 160 }
  validates :number_of_rounds,  :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }

end
```

Round model:

```
class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Controllers for that model:

```
class RoundsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @rounds = @tournament.rounds
  end

  def new
    @round = Round.new
    render action: 'new'
  end

  def create
    #@round = Round.new(round_params)
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end

 private

   def round_params
     params.require(round).permit(:tournament_id)
   end
end
```

So far, everything works great, but I can show all rounds of tournament. When I try to do that, console display this error:

```
undefined method `rounds' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried many solutions from this site, but none of them work.

This is view for index action:

```
.container
%h2 Rounds
  -if @rounds.any?
    .row
        -@rounds.each do |round|
            .col-md-2.round
                %h3 Round #{round.number}
                %p Tournament id: #{round.tournament_id}
-else
    .jumbotron
        %p This tournament has not yet any rounds.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem, and it was easier than I thought.
I added two lines of code to tournaments_controller:`

```
`   def show
        @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:id])
        @rounds = @tournament.rounds
    end
```

And I updated my view for tournament's show action:

```
    -if @rounds.any?
      .row
        -@rounds.each do |round|
          .col-md-2.round
            %h3 Round #{round.number}
            %p Tournament id: #{round.tournament_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
undefined method `rounds' for nil:NilClass
```

Means that the class tournament is not defined in the Rounds controller.
Your Tournament model define that a Tournament has many Rounds, and your Round model define that a round belongs to a tournament.

So basically, if you want to display all the rounds and the id of the tournament they belongs to, you controller should be something like that :

```
      def index
         @rounds = Rounds.all
      end
```

and assuming there is a tournament_id column in your Round table serving as foreign key for your relationship your view could looks like that :

```
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Rounds</h2>
           <% @rounds.each do |round| %>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md2">
                  <h3>Round <%= round.number %></h3>
                  <p>Tournament id: <%= round.tournament_id %></p>
                </div>
              </div>
           <% end %>
        </div>
```

Comment: This was my first idea for my problem. 
Unfortunately, this code also displays rounds of other tournaments.

Comment: the issue here, is that you are in your rounds controller, so if you want to get all the rounds for a specific tournament, you must define your what tournament to get rounds for. if you have the id this can be really simple with a simple Tournament.find(id) and then retrieving all it rounds

Comment: ok i got your mistake, rethink your app, you want to get all the rounds of a tournament. So this action should be in the Tournament controller :) and since you want to get all the rounds from a specific tournament, this should belong to the show_tournament view. you get what i mean ?

Answer (score 0):

tournament is undefined. You're tournaments resource should have rounds nested inside, and then you should find the tournament with a Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id]) in your index method.